# nginx crit error tlsv1 bad certificate status response:SSL alert number 113

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, nginx

I´m using nignx 1.4.6 with a let`s encrypt cert and getting a critical error in the nginx logs from time to time:

[crit] 67#0: *2690713 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14094459:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 bad certificate status response:SSL alert number 113) while SSL handshaking, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: 0.0.0.0:443

I can see that the client always tries to connect 3 times and the connection seems to get canceled.

I don't know if its a error is caused by the server or the client.

Can someone get me some info? Thanks guys.

Comment: This site https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/DCRUM123/Managing+SSL+Alert+Codes says that 113 means bad_certificate_status_response
113
Sent by the client if he gets an invalid certificate status response after having sent a CertificateStatusRequest extension, fatal.